# how to use filter and order together in nodejs in gcp datastore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

The code will generate error:no matching index found
let query = datastore_client.datastore.createQuery(constants.GCP_DATASTORE_NAMESPACE, constants.GCP_DATASTORE_ENTITY_TERM)
    .order('date')
    .filter('country_code', '=', country_code)

Comment: Any solution for the above?